# ASP NET MVC href to an image?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, href

I have the following razor syntax to get the picture from controller (From database table):

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID, @class = "img-responsive" })" height="300" width="230" alt="" />
```

Which works just fine i can get the images in `<img>` tags as you can see in above code.
Now in the template i downloaded it for my project i have this here below, which is a `href` styled with a button to zoom the image with fancy box:

```
<a href="../../assets/frontend/pages/img/products/model1.jpg" class="btn btn-default fancybox-button">Zoom</a>
```

The code line above works if i give a straight forward path for the image (path for the image within a folder or something not database) but i can't get it working fetching the image from database and then show it on a fancy box which fancier. 
Thank You!
**EDIT:** Not to forget the images are in the database table.

Comment: You could always create a handler .ashx that receives the Id of the product and returns the image from datatable.

Comment: any example or just a link to get knowledge about? @SílvioN.

Comment: misunderstood the question. already removed my answer.

Comment: @NaserDostdar your `@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID, @class = "img-responsive" })` is supposed to return a file right? so what happens when you use it with anchor tag href with zoom?? the file must fetched as if its doeas with physical path..

Comment: nothing happens give me an error @Reddy

Comment: ok have you tried to pass the data as byte array and use base 64 string to render the image?

Comment: I have two different field in my sql table one is used to save the varbinary data and the second one is a field type of nvarchar @Reddy

Comment: @NaserDostdar since your anchor tag requires a href path, I think it might be good if you can create a file temporarily in any folder and then pass that path to your anchor tag.. You can delete the file later when you are done with it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the full url there, without `../` I think

Answer (score 0):

> but now I would like to have a href (link) to that specific picture
>   how can I do it?

You just need to wrap your image inside a anchor tag.

```
<a href="someURL">
 <img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID, @class = "img-responsive" })" height="300" width="230" alt="" />
</a>
```

Comment: That is not what i want!

Comment: @NaserDostdar oh my bad, Can you explain a bit more of your requirement, better edit your question with more details. I will delete this answer soon..

Comment: this question will be updated soon please check and answer me accordingly, thank you

Comment: @NaserDostdar Yes I understood your question, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below. Set the **href** attribute of anchor tag (<a>) to where you want or what the operation you want to perform when user clicks on the picture.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID})">
                    <img src="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID, @class = "img-responsive" })" height="300" width="230" alt="" />
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the image link and the `Url.Content` in razor like this example:

```
<img src="@Url.Content(item.Image)" alt="MyImage" />
```

or:

```
<a href="@Url.Content(item.Image)">Load Image</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <a href="@Url.Action("GetMainPicture", "Product", new { item.ProductID)">
       <img src="@Url.Content(@item.image)" class="img-responsive " style="height="300" width="230"" alt="@item.ContName" />
</a>
```

i have used this approach to take the client to a new form where he gets all the detail about the product and this is working for me so it may help you